# Checkbox - Centring the button

Tags: android

I am trying to make a Custom ChedckBox and having a trouble centring the button part of it. Here is the code :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/checkbox_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/checkbox_height"
        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background_info"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/classification_uk_selected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_star_info">

        </CheckBox>

</FrameLayout>
```

The Drawbale just has a yellow star with no background for enabled and grey one for disabled. It stays to the left handside and I cannot get it centered

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

If you change FrameLayout to RelativeLayout you can just set android:center_in_parent to true;

Comment: Does not move it at all, its as it is locked to left hand side

Answer (score 0):

in your frame layout set gravity as center.
android:gravity="center"

Comment: Does not move it at all, its as it is locked to left hand side

Comment: android:layout_width="@dimen/checkbox_height"
you are setting layout width as your checkbox height is that correct....

Comment: @BharatSharma gravity is for text

Comment: no gravity in your frame layout you have to set so that all its child will move towards center

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe this is possible (atleast not in API version 8)

Here is the code from CompoundButton.onDraw, which seems to indicate the CompoundButton draws buttonDrawable (which represents your checkbox image) within a bounding rect which has an offset of 0 in the parent view.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final Drawable buttonDrawable = mButtonDrawable;
    if (buttonDrawable != null) {
        final int verticalGravity = getGravity() & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
        final int height = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        int y = 0;

        switch (verticalGravity) {
            case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                y = getHeight() - height;
                break;
            case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
                break;
        }

        buttonDrawable.setBounds(0, y, buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), y + height);
        buttonDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Instead, try setting the width of the CheckBox to be slightly greater (in dp) than the size of the image you're using. This squeezes the button drawable and it doesn't render with all the white space on the right.